# Java>=8 call a default method on interface in a static context with instanceof instance?

Tags: java, java-8

I was typing and i wonder how can i call a default method on a static context i have a snippet like this.

```
interface InterfaceWithDefaultMethod{  
   public default void saySomething(final int a,final int b){System.out.println(String.format("Parameters are %d %d",a,b));}
}
public class StaticsMethodIsNotOverriden2 implements InterfaceWithDefaultMethod {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      final StaticsMethodIsNotOverriden2 clazz = new StaticsMethodIsNotOverriden2();
      clazz.saySomething(13,20);//Overriden method call with 13 20
      clazz.callDefaultSaySomethingFromInstance();//Parameters are 1 2        
      /*HOW CALL public default void saySomething(final int a,final int b) METHOD HERE....????*/
      clazz.InterfaceWithDefaultMethod.super.saySomething(1, 2);/*no enclosing instance of type InterfaceWithDefaultMethod is in scope*/        
   }    

   @Override
   public void saySomething(int a, int b) {
      System.out.println(String.format("Overriden method call with %d %d",a,b));
   }
   //THIS IS WHAT A WANT TO DO BUT IN STATIC CONTEXT...
   private void callDefaultSaySomethingFromInstance(){
      InterfaceWithDefaultMethod.super.saySomething(1, 2); /*CALLING DEFAULT METHOD FROM INSTANCE CONTEXT*/       
   }
}
```

Is possible to call the default method of InterfaceWithDefaultMethod->saySomething method from static context using a StaticsMethodIsNotOverriden2 instance??

Sorry if the question is plain.

This is not working.

Comment: So you want to call the default implementation even if the method is overridden?

Comment: That's not possbile. If you override the method in class `A` calling the method on objects of that type will always call the overriden version of class `A`. Unless of course `A` is assigned a subtype of `A` where the method was overriden again. You can't access the overriden version. That's like overriding `equals` but then somehow accessing the default implementation.

Comment: but i can call the default method with a instance but using a instance method private void callDefaultSaySomethingFromInstance() in my case.

Comment: @chiperortiz Yes, of course, you can access the methods of your `super` from within your class when are implementing it, but not from the outside.

Comment: Why do you think, calling an instance method without an instance should be possible?

Comment: @Holger why without a instance? mate i have a instance indeed.

Comment: Then, what’s the relevance of “in a static context”?

Comment: @Holger static context i mean is the call from static context static void main in this case.

Comment: But that’s irrelevant. You would have the same problem within an instance method when you want to invoke the method on a different instance than `this`. Even when you know the reference does refer to `this`, like `final MyClass x = this; /* can’t call overridden method on x */`, the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. A `default` method is an instance method and, in this case, dynamic binding will kick in. There's no construct *for a client of an overridden method* to force the invocation of the super-implementation. This can only be done from the subclass (as you've done it in `callDefaultSaySomethingFromInstance`)

Your only option is to expose a different method in the subclass, and make that method call the implemented interface's default method:

```
class StaticsMethodIsNotOverriden2 implements InterfaceWithDefaultMethod {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ...
        clazz.superSaySomething(1, 2);
    }

    //a different name/signature needed
    public void superSaySomething(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Forcing super method call with %d %d", a, b));
        //the subclass calls default method
        InterfaceWithDefaultMethod.super.saySomething(a, b); 

    }

    @Override
    public void saySomething(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println(String.format("Overriden method call with %d %d", a, b));
    }

    ...
}
```